# Migrate ColdFusion scheduled tasks using neo-cron.xml

Tags: coldfusion, task, scheduler, coldfusion-10

We currently have two ColdFusion 10 dedicated servers which we are migrating to a single VPS server. We have many scheduled tasks on each. I have taken each of the `neo-cron.xml` files and copied the `var` XML elements, from within the `struct type='coldfusion.server.ConfigMap'` XML element, and pasted them within that element in the `neo-cron.xml` file on the new server. Afterward I restarted the ColdFusion service, log into cf admin, and the tasks all show as expected.

My problem is, when I try to update any of the tasks I get the following error when saving:

> An error occured scheduling the task. Unable to store Job :
>   'SERVERSCHEDULETASK#$%^DEFAULT.job_MAKE CATALOGS (SITE CONTROL)',
>   because one already exists with this identification

Also, when I try to delete a task it tells me a task with that name does not exist. So it seems to me that the task information must also be stored elsewhere. So there when I try to update a task, the record doesn't exist in the secondary location so it tries to add it new to the `neo-cron.xml` file, which causes an error because it already exists. And when trying to delete, it doesn't exist in the secondary location so it says a task with that name does not exist. That is just a guess though.

Any ideas how I can get this to work without manually re-creating dozens of tasks? From what I've read this should work, but I need to be able to edit the tasks.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of hair-pulling I was able to figure out the problem. It all boiled down to having parentheses in the scheduled task names. This was causing both the "Unable to store Job : 'SERVERSCHEDULETASK#$%^DEFAULT.job_MAKE CATALOGS (SITE CONTROL)', because one already exists with this identification" error and also causing me to be unable to delete jobs. I believe it has something to do with encoding the parentheses because the actual neo-cron.xml name attribute of the var element encodes the name like so:

serverscheduletask#$%^default#$%^MAKE CATALOGS &#X28;SITE CONTROL&#X29;

Note that this anomaly did not exist on ColdFusion 10, Update 10, but does exist on Update 13. I'm not sure which update broke it, but there you go.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to copy the neo-cron.xml from C:\ColdFusion10\\lib of one server to another. After that restart the server to make the changes effective. Login to the CF Admin and check the functionality.

This should work.

**Note:-** Please take a backup of the existing neo-cron.xml, before making the changes.

Comment: Thank you Anit. I had copied the neo-cron.xml file correctly. Please see my answer for the actual reason which I found.